# WCF binding programatically and adding metadata excange

Tags: wcf

My problem is im trying to enable mex on a service that uses net.tcp binding.
that binding is for localhost port 5000, when i want to enable mex on the same port, and have it avilable for http i have to enable the HttpGetEnabled on the Service host. All this works well but when i try to add the binding it fails becuase the binding is "net.tcp://localhost:5000/test". is there a way to enable mex on the same port but with a diffrent uri?

Without enableing NetTcpPortSharing.

I dont think the code is the issue since i can add the MEX on a diffrent port through the code an it works fine, the question is how to have net.tcp://localhost:5000/test as the WCF tcp based enpoint and net.tcp://localhost:5000/test/mex as the http mex endpoint that gives the WSDL for the TCP endpoint.

thanks,
  Totem

Comment: can you show us your config and/or your code adding these endpoints??

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  Does the different URL resolve to the same physical IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion This cant be done without port sharing.
adding meta data for the net.tcp based endpoint is quite simple and in most cases automatically done, the problem is you have to assign a new port if you want to have http based metadata if you enable HttpGetEnabled.